# jquery $(this).parent()... not working from function called externally

Tags: jquery, function

as you see in the code below. I have a jQuery function called externally.

I don't understand why I can't get the class name, I get an alert with "undefined", I was expecting "classifyClass" instead, can you help? Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>parent</title>
    <script src="./js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            function classify() {
                //some jquery stuff here alredy, and it works...

                //now I want to get/set the parent class, but not working (getting an alert with written "undefined", why?
                var myclass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
                alert(myclass);
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="pos">
    <div class="classifyClass">
        <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;" onclick="javascript:classify();return false;"></div>
        <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:green;" onclick="javascript:classify();return false;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="feedback"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

P.s. I don't want to use the jquery selector I need to call the function like that as I'm passing some asp.net parameters, I simplified here the example to focus on the main problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current context `this` refers to the `window` object.  You either need to pass `this`, like this:

```
onclick="return classify(this);"
```

With matching script:

```
function classify(elem) {
  //some jquery stuff here alredy, and it works...
  var myclass = $(elem).parent().attr('class');
  alert(myclass);
  return false;
}
```

Or (better), binding unobtrusively (using your current function, `this` will work), like this:

```
$(".classifyClass > div").click(classify);
```

Comment: in my original example the function has 2 parameters: classify(articleId,rating)... ok I tried to add the elem parameter as you suggested and add "this" inside the function call itself and using $(elem) instead of $(this). It works, thanks!

Comment: @firepol - welcome, I'd go the unobtrusive route though...you can use `data-` attributes or bind individually (getting the rating, etc relative to the clicked element...just a suggestion, it makes life *much* easier :)

Comment: Nick, I would also like the unobtrusive method... but I have a bunch of divs for each article I want to rate. now I pass the articleId from the code behind (asp.net). How could I do it with the unobtrusive method? Life is much easier like this ;) but maybe I'll redo my web app from scratch and make it completely jquery/ajax. Thx again. Cheers